# Integral of squared dot product (quadratic form)

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, inner-products

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R},$ $F(v):= (\pi T)^{-d/2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{|v|^2}{T}}$ and $ T > 0 $ is a real constant. So we have for the moments

$$(1) \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} F(v) \, \mathrm{d}v = 1$$
$$(2 )\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} vF(v) \, \mathrm{d}v = 0$$
$$(3) \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |v|^2F(v) \, \mathrm{d}v = \frac{d}{2}T.$$

Let $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$ another function with $g \in L^2(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ a bounded, connected and sufficient regular subset.

Now consider the integral (by Fubini)
$$ \int_{\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^d} |g(x) \cdot v|^2 F(v) \, \mathrm{d}(v,x) = 
\int_{\Omega} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |g(x) \cdot v|^2 F(v) \, \mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}x. $$
I would like to write this integral like
$$ \dots = \int_{\Omega} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |g(x)|^2|v|^2 F(v) \, \mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}x,$$ without the dot product. Maybe with a multiplicative constant. By Cauchy-Schwarz we would easily get the estimate from above but I would need equality. (Jensen is unfortunately not helpful here.) Preferably without explicit computation by use of $F.$ An computation by explicitly using $F$ would work but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining $f$ as the version of $F$ when $d=1$, we have $F(v) = \prod_{k=1}^d f(v_k)$. Let's also write $|g(x)\cdot v|^2$ as :
\begin{align*}
|g(x)\cdot v|^2
&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^d g_i(x)v_i\right)^2
= \sum_{i=1}^d g_i(x)v_i \sum_{j=1}^d g_j(x)v_j \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^d {g_i(x)}^2{v_i}^2 + \sum_{\substack{i,j=1 \\ i\neq j}}^d g_i(x)g_j(x)v_iv_j
\end{align*}

By Fubini, we have :
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega\times\mathbb{R}^d} |g(x)\cdot v|^2 F(v)\,\mathrm{d}(v,x)
&= \sum_{i=1}^d \int_\Omega {g_i(x)}^2
\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} {v_i}^2 F(v)\,\mathrm{d}v}_{(i)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\\
&
+ \sum_{\substack{i,j=1 \\ i\neq j}}^d g_i(x)g_j(x)
\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} v_iv_j F(v)\,\mathrm{d}v}_{(ii)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

We now use $f$ to take care of $(i)$ and $(ii)$. First, for $(i)$ :
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} {v_i}^2 F(v)\,\mathrm{d}v
&=
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} {v_i}^2 \prod_{k=1}^d f(v_k)\,\mathrm{d}v
\\
&=
\left(\vphantom{\int_R}\right.
\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}} {v_i}^2 f(v_i)\,\mathrm{d}v_i}_{=\frac{1}{2}T}
\left.\vphantom{\int_R}\right)
\left(\vphantom{\int_R}\right.
\prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\neq i}}^d \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(v_k)\,\mathrm{d}v_k}_{=1}
\left.\vphantom{\int_R}\right)
\\
&=\frac{T}{2},
\end{align*}
and for $(ii)$ :
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} v_iv_j F(v)\,\mathrm{d}v
&=
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} v_iv_j \prod_{k=1}^d f(v_k)\,\mathrm{d}v
\\
&=
\left(\vphantom{\int_R}\right.
\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}} v_i f(v_i)\,\mathrm{d}v_i}_{=0}
\left.\vphantom{\int_R}\right)
\left(\vphantom{\int_R}\right.
\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}} v_j f(v_j)\,\mathrm{d}v_j}_{=0}
\left.\vphantom{\int_R}\right)
\left(\vphantom{\int_R}\right.
\prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\neq i,j}}^d \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(v_k)\,\mathrm{d}v_k}_{=1}
\left.\vphantom{\int_R}\right)
\\
&= 0,
\end{align*}
and so our whole integral becomes :
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega\times\mathbb{R}^d} |g(x)\cdot v|^2 F(v)\,\mathrm{d}(v,x)
&=
\frac{T}{2} \sum_{i=1}^d \int_\Omega {g_i(x)}^2
\,\mathrm{d}x
\\
&=
\frac{T}{2}\|g\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2.
\end{align*}